# Issues with returning map loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, iterator, stdmap

I have a map that contains a string to sprite association. This function is used to return the sprite to draw on the screen. Here is the function:

```
sf::Sprite LoopSprite()
{
    for (std::map<std::string,sf::Sprite>::iterator it=SpriteMap.begin(); it!=SpriteMap.end(); ++it)
    {
       return it->second;
    }
}
```

I used to have these in a vector which made loops for drawing easy, but I wanted to use a map to allow easier recognition for maintaining code. The function above only allows one image from the map to be drawn. Is there something wrong with this function?

```
sf::Sprite LoopSprite(int element)
{
    return vec[element];
}
```

As pointed this works because it takes an element so there is only one return, but I want the same result except with the map. The issue is that it is easy to send in a 0-vec.size. My only idea is to have a vector of strings to allow easy looping.

Comment: How are you attempting to use this function? It will simply `return` the first `sf::Sprite` on the first iteration. It wouldn't work with vectors either.

Comment: You are returning in the first iteration itself!

Comment: In other words, your function does the same as: `sf::Sprite LoopSprite() { return SpriteMap.begin()->second; }`

Comment: That's what I was worried about. The vector function took in an int to return an individual element and the loop was outside. I am thinking about trying to approach this with a vector of strings heh

Comment: I have a hard time trying to figure out what you want to do. Can you show the vector equivalent that you want to replace with map?

Comment: I posted what I do with the vector equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function will simply `return` in the first iteration, returning only the first element in the map.

You say in the comments that originally, when you were using a vector, the function took an `int` argument and returned that element. If you still want the function, you can achieve the same with a map like so:

```
sf::Sprite LoopSprite(std::string key)
{
    return SpriteMap[key];
}
```

If you want to iterate over the elements of the map inside `LoopSprite`, then you'll need to move the lines of code that actually do something with each element into the function:

```
void LoopSprite()
{
    for (std::map<std::string,sf::Sprite>::iterator it=SpriteMap.begin(); it!=SpriteMap.end(); ++it)
    {
       // Do something with it->second
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you are returning local variable which is not allowed. Even after returning from the function it may be null or invalid.

You are only returning this part `SpriteMap.begin()` which is actually useless. This code is much easier.

```
sf::Sprite LoopSprite(string key)
{
    std::map<std::string,sf::Sprite>::iterator it = SpriteMap.begin();

    while(it!=SpriteMap.end())
    {
       if(check) // check if this is your desired key
           return value;
       ++it;
    }
    return null;
}
```

map is used usually in a simple way:

```
string key = "keyItem";    
sf::Sprite ans = SpriteMap[key];
```